# Convert setTimeout to async awesomeness?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm still grappling with async await and often end up using a set timeout to quickly solve my problem hackily.

I'm getting data with jquery get and calling the buildSlideshow function on `.done();`

After the slideshow is built, I want to call the `startSlideshow()` function with another function.

I've tried various versions of async and await but can't seem to nail it, and without a timeout of some sort, the slideshow starts before it's fully build, with funky results.

```
$.get('/data/backgrounds.json').done((data) => {
      bgData = data;
      buildSlideshow(bgData.find(findVenue));
    });
  function findVenue(page) {
    return page.page === currentPage;
}

function buildSlideshow(page) {
  page.bgs.forEach((bg) => {
    bgUrl = bg.url ? bg.url : '';
    venueName = bg.venue ? bg.venue : '';
    venueLocation = bg.cityState ? bg.cityState : '';
    caption = `${venueName}<br>${venueLocation}`;
    div = document.createElement('div');
    $(div).append(caption);
    $(div).css('background-image', `linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(8, 0, 14, 0.3) 0%, rgba(8, 0, 14, 0) 100%), url(${bgUrl})`);
    $('#bgSlideshow').append(div);
  });
}

function startSlideshow() {
  $('#bgSlideshow > div:gt(0)').hide();

  setInterval(() => {
    $('#bgSlideshow > div:first')
      .fadeOut(2000)
      .next()
      .fadeIn(2000)
      .end()
      .appendTo('#bgSlideshow');
  }, 8000);
}
// doesn't work
startSlideshow();

// does work
setTimeout(() => {
  startSlideshow();
}, 300);
```

Comment: _"I'm getting data with jquery get and calling the buildSlideshow function on .done();"_ show that code. Most of your slideshow setup code here isn't too relevant.

Comment: unclear why you would need to use timeouts. What is asynchronous. I see nothing in that code that is.

Comment: @AlexWayne I added the json call but it's not the problem. Getting / awaiting the data is not my problem, it's that the slideShow() starts before the forEach loop building the slideshow has appended all the divs.

Comment: @KirkRoss in fact, it starts before the forEach loop even begins. Even before the server receives the request for the slides.

Comment: Put the call to startSlideshow() after buildSlideshow()?

Answer (score -1):

Stripping what's unimportant here you basically have this:

```
$.get('/data/backgrounds.json').done((data) => {
  buildSlideshow(data.find(findVenue));
});

startSlideshow();
```

What happens here is:

1. You request your data, and provide a callback to run when that's done, bu t the fetch is pending.
2. You start the slideshow.
3. Sometime later, the request for data resolves and triggers your callback.

You simply need to move the call to `startSlideshow` into your callback where you build the slideshow, since you can't start it until you've built it.

```
$.get('/data/backgrounds.json').done((data) => {
  buildSlideshow(data.find(findVenue));
  startSlideshow();
});
```